# ASP.NET Show StyleSheet In Logon Page

Tags: asp.net

I want to use my site style sheet on the logon page.

I have the following in my web.Config but I'm not allowed at the css page unless I'm logged in

```
  <location>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/App_Themes/Layout.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users = "*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: I think you might have forgotten to paste whatever it was you had in your config. :)

Comment: It turns out it due to running in Visual Studio Web Server localhost:[no] instaed of just in IIS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have the first location tag- remove that. The config should be (assuming you are using Forms authentication):

```
    <configuration>
       <system.web>
         <authentication mode="Forms"> 
         </authentication>
         <authorization>
           <deny users="?" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
       <location path="App_Themes/Layout.css">
          <system.web>
            <authorization>
              <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
          </system.web>
       </location>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is about the path in here :

```
<location path="~/App_Themes/Layout.css">
```

try to put exac location of the css file like that :

```
<location path="App_Themes/Layout.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the CSS style sheet in the HTML head tag...

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
```

Hope that helps **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in the allow tag for your CSS:

```
<allow users="*,?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give id to the head tag of the page and then add the external css to this head when your page is loaded.